# Could not target platform: 'Java SE 11' using tool chain: 'JDK 8 (1.8)'

Tags: spring-boot, heroku

Trying to deploy my app to heroku, but it keeps failing with the error:
Could not target platform: 'Java SE 11' using tool chain: 'JDK 8 (1.8)'

I have my JAVA_HOME,JAVA_PATH,and so on.. set up, i have an image of all of them here, i think they are correct. If i check java -version, and javac -version, they both show java 11.

I also tried putting to the root folder a system.properties.txt file and also instead of .txt a .gradle file with java.runtime.version=11   inside it.

Also i have this in my build.gradle:

```
sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
```

But it keeps installing jdk8 at the start of the deploy(git push heroku master) like this:

```
Gradle app detected
remote: -----> Spring Boot detected
remote: -----> Installing JDK 1.8... done
remote: -----> Building Gradle app...
remote: -----> executing ./gradlew build -x test
remote:        Downloading https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.4.1-all.zip
```

here are the Images of the deploy failing and the environmental variables that are set up.

[image]
[image]

I have been with this problem for a week now, i think i tried all, but i would be really greatful if someone could help me with this. Thank you!

Comment: It should be in file called system.properties so without the txt, did you check that?

Comment: No, i actually have not..seems like i am a dummy dum. Thanks alot, it does work now:)!

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem getting a "Java SE 11 using tool chain JDK 8" error. After Googling the problem, I was hinted toward the JAVA_HOME settings.

I use sdkman to manage my Java and Kotlin versions current version settings so after checking the current Java version configured in sdkman, I realized it was pointing to the GraalVM version 19 which targets Java 8.

So I simply reinstated the current JAVA_HOME to 11 with "sdkman use java 11.0.1-zulu" and everything was working fine.

Softjake

Answer (score 3):

Add a **system.properties** file to your project with this line of code.

```
java.runtime.version=11
```

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like [you already solved your problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57514259/could-not-target-platform-java-se-11-using-tool-chain-jdk-8-1-8#comment101497482_57514259) by renaming `system.properties.txt` to `system.properties`. (By the way, [it's okay to answer your own question!](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer))

In case it's helpful for anyone else, this is the official documentation from Heroku:

> Create a `system.properties` file if one does not already exist, specify the version, and commit it to git. Supported version are described in the [Java Support article](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/java-support#supported-java-versions). The file’s contents should look something like this:
>
> ```
> java.runtime.version=11
> ```

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/customizing-the-jdk#specify-a-jdk-version

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem using openjdk 11 in linux Ubuntu. 
But it worked ok in my work laptop. Same OS Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. 
I checked version of jdk in my laptop it was:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java
```

but it inside is using tool chain: 'JDK 10 (1.10)'
so I got this message

```
using tool chain: 'JDK 10 (1.10)'
```

I check my work laptop and it has

```
 openjdk version "11.0.4" 2019-07-16
 OpenJDK Runtime Environment AdoptOpenJDK (build 11.0.4+11)
 OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM AdoptOpenJDK (build 11.0.4+11, mixed mode)
```

Searching about openjdk I discovered this site
 [https://adoptopenjdk.net](https://adoptopenjdk.net/)
where I could get OpenJDK 11 (LTS) build 11.0.4+11

After I added it to alternatives

```
sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/java" "java" "/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-11.0.4+11/bin/java" 1
sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/javac" "javac" "/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-11.0.4+11/bin/javac" 1
sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/javadoc" "javadoc" "/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-11.0.4+11/bin/javadoc" 1
```

and then choose everyone of them

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
sudo update-alternatives --config javac
sudo update-alternatives --config javadoc
```

After problem was solved.
I hope this can help someone else.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why but heroku doesnt't detect provided by gradle version

```
sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
```

Once I changed it to plain string JDK 11 was detected

```
sourceCompatibility = '11'
targetCompatibility = '11'
```

result:

```
remote: -----> Building on the Heroku-20 stack
remote: -----> Using buildpack: heroku/jvm
remote: -----> heroku-deploy app detected
remote: -----> Installing JDK 11... done
remote: -----> Discovering process types
remote:        Procfile declares types -> web
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I opened Android Studio and clicked on the “Android gradle plugin can be upgraded” notification to solve the issue